# Hibernate: collection delete child

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity called "House" that contains multiple "Room"s, which is setup as follows:

House.java:

```
@Entity
public class House {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Item> rooms;
    ...
}
```

Room.java:

```
@Entity
public class Room {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "houseId")
    private House house;
    ...
}
```

Now, if I delete a room directly via the entity manager it is not deleted:

```
getEntityManager().contains(room); // returns true
getEntityManager().remove(room);
getEntityManager().flush();
```

If I delete it from the collection, it is deleted:

```
house.getRooms().remove(room);
getEntityManager().persist();
getEntityManager().flush();
```

Can anyone explain me this behavior?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In second example you have to `persist` house to make room remove effective.

In first code you are removing object from `EntityManager persistence context` (and entity manager register you deletion) and `flush()` apply this operation removing room from database.

In second example you call `List.remove()`: you are not advice `EntityManager` to delete object from database; `orphanRemoval` will works when you call `entityManager().persist(house)` because when you do `house.getRooms().remove(room)` you are modify house and need to tell entityManager to apply this modification with `EntityManager.persist()`; `orphanRemoval` do the rest deleting removed room because detected as orphan

Comment: You are right, I just forgot to copy the line "getEntityManager().flush();". 
But in the first example the entity is not removed from the database and still exists in the collection "house.getRooms()".

Comment: I think you have to set `room.setHouse(null)` before room deletion to indicate Hibernate your single object (not deleted via `List.remove()`) is not yet attached to any house and can be safely deleted